# Data Error Checking

Tags: serial-port, crc

I've got a bit of an odd question. A friend of mine and I thought it would be funny to make a serial port kind of communication between computers using sound. Basically, computers emit a series of beeps to send data, and listen for beeps over a microphone to receive data. In short, the world's most annoying serial port. I have all of the basics worked out. I can filter out sounds of only one frequency and I have sent data from one computer to another. Although the transmission is fairly error free, being affected only by very loud noises, some issues still exist. My question is, what are some good ways to check the data for errors and, more importantly, recover from these errors.

My serial communication is very standard once you get past the fact it uses sound waves. I use one start bit, 8 data bits, and one stop bit in every frame. I have already considered Cyclic Redundancy Checks, and I plan to factor this into my error checking, but CRCs don't account for some of the more insidious issues. For example, consider sending two bytes of data. You send the first one, and it received correctly, but just after the stop bit of the first byte, and the start bit of the next, a large book falls on the floor, which the receiver interprets to be a start bit, now the true start bit is read as part of the data and the receiver could be reading garbage data for many bytes to come. Eventually, a pause in the data could get things back on track.

That isn't the worst of it though. Bits can be dropped too, and most error checking schemes I can think of rely on receiving a certain number of bytes. What happens when the receiver keeps waiting for bytes that may not come?

So, you can see the complexity of this question. If you can direct me to any resources, or just give me a few tips, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CRC is just a part of the solution.  You can check for bad data but then you have to do something about it.  The transmitter has to re-send the data, it needs to be told to do that.  A protocol.

The starting point is that you split up the data into packets.  A common approach is a start byte that indicates the start of the packet, followed by a packet number, followed by a length byte that indicates the length of the packet.  Followed by the data bytes and the CRC.  The receiver sends an ACK or NAK back to indicate success.

This solves several problems:

- you don't care about a bad start bit anymore, the pause you need to recover is always there
- you start a timer when you receive the first bit or byte, declare failure when the timer expires before the entire packet is received
- the packet number helps you recover from bad ACK/NAK returns.  The transmitter times out and resends the packet, you can detect the duplicate

[RFC 916](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc916) describes such a protocol in detail.  I never heard of anybody actually implementing it (other than me).  Works pretty well.

Comment: My biggest issue was inserting a pause only when it was needed, and although I had considered packets indicating success or failure, time-outs had not occurred to me as a solution for this problem. I had always assumed a timeout was to keep your program from blocking indefinitely read/write command when the line broke or something (well, it obviously solves this as well). This protocol makes a lot of sense. Obviously I have not read the document you linked in its entirety yet, but it appears to be exactly what I am looking for. So, thanks for the tips AND resources :)

Comment: Hans's solution is good for dealing with unreliable packet based communications, but you have an additional problem in that serial port data isn't framed into packets.  If you drop a book and lose alignment, you need to be able to re-sync to a future packet.  You can get around this by encapsulating your data into frames with special delimiter bytes and escape sequences.  HDLC is commonly used for this purpose of "packetizing" serial data for reliability